# Angular2: Http.get<Object[]> map undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-services, http-get

I have a service defined with these imports:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";
import { Navigation } from "../Shared/app.home";
import { Module } from "../Shared/app.home";
```

Then in the service I define a method:

```
getNavigationModules(): Observable<Navigation[]> {
    return this.http.get<Module[]>("/api/modules/getuserpreferences").map((mods) => {
        return mods.map(m => {
            var nav = new Navigation();
            nav.id = m.Id;
            nav.name = m.Name;
            nav.isFavorite = m.IsFavorite;
            nav.url = m.FriendlyUrl;
            nav.status = (m.ModuleProperties["Status"] != null && m.ModuleProperties["Status"] === "Online") ? "on" : "off" ;
            nav.type = m.Type;

            return nav;
        });
    });
}
```

When the method is called, I get the error that map is undefined. 
When calling mods.map I assume that by calling http.get that mods will be an Module array, but when I use the debugger (Chrome) I see that the debugger treats mods as an Object with a property Modules, this one being the Module array.

[image]

But if I change the code to mods.Modules.map I get an error when compiling because mods is in fact an Module[] and not an object.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: unless you subscribe it will be `undefined`

Comment: But I want to return an Observable, and subscribe returns a Subscription.

Comment: Can you reproduce using a plunker or stackblitz

Comment: I was doing it, but @JB Nizet posted a solution that works. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're telling TypeScript that what the backend will send back is an array of Module. But it's not. It's an object, with one field named `Modules`, which is an array of Module. So tell the correct thing to TypeScript:

```
getNavigationModules(): Observable<Navigation[]> {
    return this.http.get<{Modules: Module[];}>("/api/modules/getuserpreferences").map((mods) => {
        return mods.Modules.map(m => {
            var nav = new Navigation();
            nav.id = m.Id;
            nav.name = m.Name;
            nav.isFavorite = m.IsFavorite;
            nav.url = m.FriendlyUrl;
            nav.status = (m.ModuleProperties["Status"] != null && m.ModuleProperties["Status"] === "Online") ? "on" : "off" ;
            nav.type = m.Type;

            return nav;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: That's it :) Thx!